# Blazor handling asp pages

Tags: asp.net, blazor-server-side

I have migrated old ASP pages ([www.company.com/index.asp](http://www.company.com/index.asp)) to the Blazor project and I am trying to display "Not Found page" to the users accessing web site via "old bookmarks" like [www.company.com/contact.asp](http://www.company.com/contact.asp).

I have tried in the _host.cshtml redirection, but condition is never met.

```
@if ((Request.Path.ToString()?.Contains(".asp")).GetValueOrDefault())
{
    LocalRedirect("/NotFound");
    return;
}
```

I have tried to add @page directive `@page "/{oldPage}.asp"` to NotFound blazor component, but application does not render any page at all then.

I would rather solve *asp handling in the application itself rather than on the IIS or proxy, because I do not have direct access to proxy/IIS settings.

Is there any hint how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add to Startup.cs `endpoints.MapGet("/{page}.asp", async x => { x.Response.Redirect("/NotFound"); });`

Full snippet:

```
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
                endpoints.MapGet("/{page}.asp", async x => { x.Response.Redirect("/NotFound"); });
            });
```